# java.lang.NullPointerException at frame.add(Object)

Tags: java, swing, exception, jpanel, paint

I'm trying to do a simple software that will draws a rectangle and some rows but i have a unexpected **java.lang.NullPointerException** when i try to add my panel (extended to JPanel) at my JFrame.
The code is:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

import com.Entity.robot.Map;




import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;



public class MainWindow {
private JFrame frame;
private JFileChooser fileChooser;
private MapGUI panel;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public MainWindow() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {

    panel= new MapGUI();
    panel.setBounds(200, 100, 500, 250);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel); <---- THE EXCEPTION IS HERE**
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1500, 900);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

         JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenuItem mntmOpenMapFrom = new JMenuItem("Open map from...");
        mnFile.add(mntmOpenMapFrom);
    }

}



class MapGUI extends JPanel {

    public MapGUI(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(1, 1, 500, 250);


    }

}
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel); <---- THE EXCEPTION IS HERE**
frame = new JFrame();
```

In the above code, you haven't defined what `frame` is until the line after the exception. Switch their order:

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason of `NullPointerException` is that you are trying to call a method on uninitialized/null `frame` object. In your code you need to initalize your `frame` object prior using it.

Just reverse these statements:

```
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel); <---- THE EXCEPTION IS HERE**
  frame = new JFrame();
```

to

```
   frame = new JFrame();
   frame.getContentPane().add(panel); <---- THE EXCEPTION IS HERE**
```